# android play http video

Tags: android, http, url, video, mp4

```
Here is my code
String url = "https://bbxzb.babaxiong.com/xiaodingdang.mp4?_upt=xxxxxxxxxxxx"
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
String query = uri.getQuery();
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
mVideoView.start();
```

my video link contains query string :

#### _upt=xxxxxx

and this is dynamic and necessary. When I open it on Chrome, it can play OK, but on Android, it always says that "Cannot play this video". How to play video like this pattern?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the Android device just cannot play this video format (encoder settings). To test : Save the same mp4 to SD card and then try to play it using any other gallery or media player apps. Did it play there?

Comment: Thanks very much.I found some Android device dose not support this format and others can play.Could you tell me is there any lib can play such video?